# How to create desktop shortcut for Chrome profile and run two or more profiles simultaneously?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dock, desktop, shortcut

I am new to Mac, and I have my rough time (missing keys, wrong shortcuts and etc). But I don't give up. I am a JS developer with more than 10 years of Windows and Linux (Debian, Ubuntu) experience and I need another Chrome profile accessible on a demand. The easiest way for me is another icon in Dock (and on the desktop).
It is very easy in Windows - one just have to make shortcut and enter command line for chrome which looks like this:
`google-chrome --profile-directory=Default`

For OS X I found command line is

`open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory=Default`

How to make a shortcut in Dock and on Desktop using it?

Please mind the subject (question), it is important for me, that shortcuts has to allow running multiple profiles simultaneously. I didn't stated it first time, because it was *obvious* for me it will work that way (Linux and Windows just do it).

Answer (score 3):

Since there are several possible answers, I will introduce a more exotic one:

- Download and install [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus)
- Create a file chromedefault.sh in ~/Documents/scripts/ with the content:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory=Default
  ```
- Open Platypus with the following settings:

  [image]

  and create a new "app" *ChromeDefault*.
- For a second app with the profile *Other* use another script chromeother.sh with appropriate changes:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory=Other
  ```

  and call it *ChromeOther*.
- Put both apps in the /Applications folder and create as many symlinks or aliases as needed.

Comment: I have a problem with this solution, when Chrome runs Default profile running command `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory=Other` makes only current Chrome window focus. How to run two or more profiles simultaneously?

Comment: @Marecky hi! Were you able to find a desired solution?

Answer (score 2):

Open Script Editor from /Application/Utilities >> create a new doc >> paste following:

```
do shell script "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --profile-directory=Profile\\ 3 > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

FYI:

`\\` contains a space (the first back slash escapes the second back slash which escapes the space!);

and user profile `../Chrome/Profile 3` will be `--profile-directory=Profile\\ 3` in the code, `../Chrome/Profile 2` will be `--profile-directory=Profile\\ 2`, `../Chrome/Default` will be `--profile-directory=Default`

Try to run it and save it if it works.

Comment: double '\' seems couldn't show, idk y..

it show be \\

Comment: do shell script "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --profile-directory=Profile\\ 3 > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

Answer (score 0):

Building on klanomath's answer, I wrote the following shell script:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/zsh

declare -a profiles=( "Default" "Profile 3" "Profile 4" )
declare -a profile_aliases=( one two three )

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    exit
fi

for n ({1..${#profile_aliases}}); do
    if [ $profile_aliases[$n] = $1 ]; then
        #echo $profiles[$n];
        /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --new-window --profile-directory="${profiles[$n]}"
    fi
done
```

this enables you to run `./chrome.sh one`, which will launch the `Default` folder. The main difference in this and the other solutions here is the `--new-window` switch, which makes Chrome run in a new window. Also, I'm just using the `Google Chrome` executable, which just made sense to me.

Answer (score -2):

just use the Automater app. its built into macOS to make the shell script into am app.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on such as *how* a user would use the Automator app to do what you're suggesting? Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.